# set state on slider event state is not a function error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I'm trying to change the state when i update a slider.
Somehow the setState is not a function error appears:

"TypeError: this.setState is not a function"

I'm new to react and i probably haven't realized yet exactly how to use the state.

```
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var React = require('react');
var SliderComponent = require('rc-slider');

class Slider extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("SLIDER");
    console.log(props);
    this.state = {
        value: 50,
    };

}
onSliderChange(value){
    console.log(value);
    this.setState({
        value: value
    });
}
render() {
    return (<div> SLider
        <SliderComponent value={this.state.value} tipTransitionName="rc-slider-tooltip-zoom-down" onChange={this.onSliderChange} />
    </div>)
}
}

module.exports = Slider;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind **this** to onSliderChange function.

```
<SliderComponent value={this.state.value} tipTransitionName="rc-slider-tooltip-zoom-down" onChange={this.onSliderChange.bind(this)} />
```

You can do this in constructor as well.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("SLIDER");
    console.log(props);
    this.state = {
        value: 50,
    };
    this.onSliderChange = this.onSliderChange.bind(this)
}
```

There is lot of other way to do this.

https://medium.com/@housecor/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56